# how to check the duplicate key in mysql dbi Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to migrate data from one db1 to other db2.

While migrating, there is possibility of duplicate primary key, then i want to over write with the db1 values. This can be achieved by on duplicate key sql statement.

But i want to store duplicate entry key into a map? how it is possible?

This is code which i have written for migration:

```
my $select = $dbh1->prepare("SELECT pr_id, name, lastname FROM person");
my $insert = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO PERSON(pr_id, name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$select->execute; 
while ( my($PR_ID,$NAME,$LASTNAME) = $select->fetchrow_array )
{
   $insert->execute($PR_ID,$NAME,$LASTNAME);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "map"? Where's your `on duplicate` statement?

Comment: my requirement is, while inserting the row from db1 to db2, if PR_ID which is primary key is  duplicate then i want to store it in map. how it can be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "a map"? Do you mean a hash?

Comment: yes. hashmap. is it possible to store in form of key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to call the following function to do it.

$h->errstr()
Returns the native database engine error message from the last DBI method called.

Refer to: https://zetcode.com/perl/dbi/